# WebService Exception- The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, iis

I have written a below method to retrieve the XML response from client web-service.
At below code, I'm receiving the error as **{"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."}**

Please help.

Error at below code

```
WebResponse webResponse = req.GetResponse();
```

**Method To Call WebService -**

```
[WebMethod]
public XmlDocument GetData()
{
    string sError = "";

    string sApiSession;

    DateTime dtRequested = DateTime.Now;

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();

    try
    {
        NetworkCredential creds = new NetworkCredential();

        creds.UserName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("UserName");
        creds.Password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Password");
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Services"));

        req.Method = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Method");
        req.ContentType = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ContentType ");
        req.Credentials = creds;

        //Retriev into webresponse
        WebResponse webResponse = req.GetResponse();

        //Read from WebResponse to datastream
        Stream dataStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

        //read the content of data stream
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
        {
            xDoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return xmlDoc = getXml(xDoc);
}
```

I have fallowed the below link, but still no result.

http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host/

Answer (score 0):

The above code working fine, If I try from our of my office network and box. at this moment we are working on network blocking.

Comment: However, This issue is resolved. As I suspected, we got Firewall blocking at network.