# How to put the firewall request for outbound webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, networking, network-programming, firewall

Moving forward from my webservice exception post

[WebService Exception- The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767199/webservice-exception-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error)

For this issue we are assuming, there is network blocking happening to my web request.
So I contacted network team, Then, they said to put a firewall request number on my web service request, then they are able to troubleshoot my web service issue for the given firewall request.

I'm new for the word "firewall request number", please help me.
How can I put the firewall request for my below web method?

Please help?

```
[WebMethod]
public XmlDocument GetData()
{
    string sError = "";

    string sApiSession;

    DateTime dtRequested = DateTime.Now;

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();

    try
    {
        NetworkCredential creds = new NetworkCredential();

        creds.UserName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("UserName");
        creds.Password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Password");
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Services"));

        req.Method = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Method");
        req.ContentType = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ContentType ");
        req.Credentials = creds;

        //Retriev into webresponse
        WebResponse webResponse = req.GetResponse();

        //Read from WebResponse to datastream
        Stream dataStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

        //read the content of data stream
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
        {
            xDoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return xmlDoc = getXml(xDoc);
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking? When you say "Request number" do you mean port? It depends on your set up but by default HTTP requests are over port 80 and HTTPS requests are over port 443. You might also mean the IP address of the server? Could you please clarify what it is you need.

Comment: Maybe they mean you should add a certain header so they can identify your request. It's impossible for us to know what "firewall request number" means as they made up the term; ask your network administrator what they mean.

Answer (score 0):

That's way I didn't find in Google. "firewall request number" is our internal request, that we have to make for network administrator.