# WebService Exception when not using fiddler tool

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, iis, fiddler

Moving forward on below issue.
**[WebService Exception- The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767199/webservice-exception-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error)**

**Step1 -** If I open the Fiddler tool to troubleshoot the above issue, I'm receiving the xml response from my client.

**Step2 -** If I close the Fiddler tool, then I'm seeing the error as "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send"

On this issue, I have contacted my network team too, they said, there is not blocking happening for this communication.

What is the problem causing with same code of fiddler tool OPEN and CLOSE?
Please give some relaxation from this issue.

Please see below attached proxy server settings  [image]

Comment: How are you calling the service (i.e. the client)? Do you have a proxy server set up?

Comment: @DavidG, Yes, I have the proxy server setup for my LAN.

Comment: Then I suspect that is the problem. In your clienthave you specified proxy settings?

Comment: My client server is out of my company. I'm not sure what they are using.                                                                Note - This code is working, If I try from out of my company network. I'm able to browse this service from same BOX(Devloping server) IE browser too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your client application requires proxy settings. Get the settings from your network admin and put them in your applications config file with the [defaultProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex(v=vs.110).aspx) element:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy usesystemdefaults="true" proxyaddress="http://your-network-proxy:port" bypassonlocal="true"/>
      <bypasslist>
        <add address="some-internal-server" />
      </bypasslist>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please see updated post with added proxy settings image, are we on same line?

Comment: You need to press advanced to see the proxy settings.

Comment: your answer is similar to my solution, but we resolved it by allowing the firewall blockings.

Answer (score 0):

See http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/13-02-28/help!-running-fiddler-fixes-my-app- for some common causes of problems that Fiddler "automatically" fixes.

The most common issue is that you've forgotten to call `Close()` on the result of a call to `GetResponseStream()`.

It's also possible that you're hitting an issue in the .NET Framework, whereby it doesn't expect a HttpWebRequest with the `KeepAlive` property set to have the server-side connection closed after a single request, and thus throws an exception when that occurs. I consider that a bug in .NET (since the HTTP specification permits closure at any time). If that's your issue you can either catch the exception and retry, or you can workaround the problem by disabling the KeepAlive property on the request object.

Answer (score 0):

However, This issue is resolved. As I suspected, we got Firewall blocking at network.